# Permitindo o fundo transparente de uma página web passar pelo resto das janelas num webbrowser control

Tags: c#

Estou a tentar fazer o fundo transparente de uma página no webbrowser control permanecer transparente permitindo ao utilizador ver o que está por baixo dessa janela, ou seja, só elementos HTML que estejam por cima do fundo transparente se verão. Usar Forms ou WPF é indiferente.

Comment: Explique melhor o seu problema. Se possível coloque algum código ou imagem que possa ilustrar a situação...

Comment: @DanielDutra É o seguinte: eu tenho uma página que tem um back transparente e quero tirar partido dele usando um webbrowser onde o fundo desse mesmo webbrowser fique transparente, sendo possível visualizar o que está por baixo desse forms no windows (todas as janelas, o desktop, etc.). Aqui está um exemplo: http://i.imgur.com/0lHwGXC.jpg (o conteúdo que a imagem contém seria a minha webpage com o fundo transparente...).

Comment: Webpage? Não seria WinForms?

Comment: @DanielDutra Não pois estou carregando uma página web pelo webbrowser control. Eu sei que é meio complicado de perceber...